# Datatype of Primary key made of two attributes in a table used as a foreign key of a different table

Tags: mysql

I am creating 3 tables in my railway database.One table(TrainTravel) uses two fields (TrainNo) and (TravelDate) as Primary key.
Another table Booking uses (TrainTravelID) as foreign key which takes the primary key of TrainTravel Table.

There should be a datatype which should be defined for (TrainTravelID) in Booking table.

railway_create.sql

```
use railway;
create table Booking(
    PassengerID int(4),
    TrainTravelID
);

create table TrainTravel(
    TrainNo int(3),
    TravelDate date,
    TrainName varchar(20),
    BoardingStation varchar(20),
    Destination varchar(20),
    Ac1Seats int(3),
    Ac3Seats int(3),
    SlSeats int(3),
    SeSeats int(3),
    constraint JourneyID PRIMARY KEY (TrainNo,TravelDate)
);

create table Person(
    Name varchar(20),
    LoginID int(4),
    Password varchar(20),
    Address varchar(50),
    Phno int(10),
    constraint PRIMARY KEY (LoginID)
);
```

railway_alter.sql

```
use railway;
alter table Booking
    add constraint fk_TrainTravelID foreign key as (TrainTravelID) references Train(JourneyID),
    add constraint fk_PassengerID foreign key as (PassengerID) references Person(LoginID);
```

I want to know the datatype of combined primary key of TrainTravel so that it can be used as datatype of TrainTravelID attribute in Booking table.

Without placing any datatype it is giving error,

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(int(3),date)
)' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

TrainTravelID has no data type in Booking.

You need a couple also in Booking.

create table Booking(
    PassengerID int(4),
    TrainNo int(3),
    TravelDate date
);

create table TrainTravel(
    TrainNo int(3),
    TravelDate date,
    TrainName varchar(20),
    BoardingStation varchar(20),
    Destination varchar(20),
    Ac1Seats int(3),
    Ac3Seats int(3),
    SlSeats int(3),
    SeSeats int(3),
    constraint JourneyID PRIMARY KEY (TrainNo,TravelDate)
);

create table Person(
    Name varchar(20),
    LoginID int(4),
    Password varchar(20),
    Address varchar(50),
    Phno int(10),
    constraint PRIMARY KEY (LoginID)
);

alter table Booking
  
  add constraint fk_TrainTravelID foreign key(TrainNo,TravelDate) references TrainTravel(TrainNo,TravelDate),
   
 add constraint fk_PassengerID foreign key(PassengerID) references Person(LoginID);